# Why do we say "rips and tears"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, comparisons, redundancy

For example, "Clothing must be free from rips and tears."

It seems to me that the words "rips" and "tears" can be used interchangeably, and that using both is redundant.

Is there a particular reason for using both? Does it have anything to do with its origins?

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129951/tear-apart-or-rip-apart-packaging

Comment: Sounds like it was written by a lawyer. Oh wait, a lawyer would say *... rips, tears, and being rendered assunder.*

Comment: *rent*....rendered is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

A rip and a tear might not always have the same meaning, but there is certainly considerable overlap.

In this example, I doubt whether it was the author's intention to distinguish the two at all: "rips" and "tears" are just being used here as a figure of speech - in order to intensify or clarify,  a bit like "aches and pains", "care and attention", "loyal and faithful" or "neat and tidy".

Answer (score 0):

"Rips" and "tears" are two different types of failure of a garment or other sewn object. A "rip" is a failure of a seam in an item, that is a place where two pieces of fabric are joined; a "tear" is a failure of a single piece of the garment other than the failure of a seam.

Further the degree with which the two types of failure can be repaired varies. A rip is relatively simple to repair without much evidence that a repair was made, because one merely has to mend the seam. Repairing a tear so that it cannot be detected requires much more skill, and takes more time.

Comment: can you provide a citation for this distinction? My dictionary doesn't agree. Its definition of _rip_ is _a long tear or cut_.